# list not displaying in angular binding?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying my first angular js list example. Having issues displaying the list, there are no errors in the console:(

html

```
<body ng-controller="mycontroller">
    <form ng-submit="addtask()">total nr of tasks: {{myvar.length}}
        <br />remaining: {{remaining()}}
        <input type="text" ng-model="newtask" />
        <ul ng-repeat="var in myvar">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myvardone" /> <span class="done-{{myvardone}}">{{var.text}}</span>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="submit">add</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

script:

```
   function mycontroller($scope) {
       $scope.myvar = [{
           text: 'bert',
           done: false
       }, {
           text: 'ed',
           done: true
       }, {
           text: 'pet',
           done: false
       }];

       $scope.addtask = function () {
           $scope.myvar.push({
               text: $scope.newtask,
               done: false
           });
       }

       $scope.remaining = function () {
           var count = 0;
           angular.forEach($scope.myvar, function (t) {
               if (t.done) {
                   count++
               } else {
                   count += 0;
               }
           });
           return count;
       }
   }
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dingen2010/vc2bC/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vc2bC/5/

Comment: You have to add `ng-app="myApp"` and `angular.module('myApp', []);` to bootstrap angular

Comment: the remaining number ie the tasks that are not strikentrhough is not working though?

Comment: Your `code` has logic error, your data `done` doesn't do the correctly . And also your `input checkbox` ng-model should like `var.done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things

One. missed `ng-app`

Two. You should not repeating `ul`, but `li`

```
<li ng-repeat="var in myvar">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="var.done" /> 
   <span class="done-{{var.done}}">{{var.text}}</span>
</li>
```

Three. when you add, you need to have task name entered.

Four, you don't need remaining function. use filter

```
{{ (myvar | filter:{done:true}).length }}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vc2bC/10/

Answer (score 1):

simple demo can be like

```
<html ng-app>xxxxx</html>
```

don't forget "ng-app"

Comment: the remaining number ie the tasks that are not strikentrhough is not working though?

Answer (score 0):

Darn, Awakening beat me to it... :/ But yeah, just simply move the ng-controller tag to a containing  and put a ng-app tag on the html tag. Here:

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/vc2bC/8/

Comment: the remaining number ie the tasks that are not strikentrhough is not working though?